# Prefer one type convert into another through implicit constructor or implicit conversion operator?

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator, implicit-constructor

Assume we have procedure `void f(X2);`. Further assume we have types `X1` and `X2` that do not share an inheritance hierarchy.

We want to call it like this: `f(X1{})` and have `X1` implicitly convert into `X2`. We have two options of achieving this:

```cpp
struct X2 {};
struct X1 { operator X2(); };
```

```cpp
struct X1 {};
struct X2 { X2(const X1&); };
```

Implementation-wise there are practical differences between the two with the order things are defined and how private data is accessed.

But from a user perspective, are there any cases where these two approaches will behave differently? If so, which of the two is preferable?

This question remains the same even if we mark both `explicit`. One difference that arises then is that conversion through the constructor is only available in the former case but `static_cast` works with either.

Comment: One practical difference is "does X2 know about X1?" versus "does X1 know about X2?".

Comment: Prefer explicit conversion.  Implicit conversions can lead to unpleasant surprises later on. [C++ Core Guidelines - C.164: Avoid implicit conversion operators](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ro-conversion)

Comment: @RichardCritten the example in the guidelines you linked is interesting because it discourages the implicit conversion from C-string to `std::string` but the other way around is fine and part of the standard library. The use case I am facing is very similar to this

Comment: If the conversion involves the construction of a new object use a constructor.

Comment: @john what is the reasoning behind your answer? It would also be possible to extract the relevant data and call a public constructor of `X2` with that data

Comment: You might also like to read [C++ Core Guidelines - C.46: By default, declare single-argument constructors explicit](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c46-by-default-declare-single-argument-constructors-explicit)

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are functionally equivalent, so as to let you define both kinds of conversion even if one of the types is a class you cannot modify, or is not a class at all, like a fundamental type.

In the implicit case, both options will let you call `f(X1{})`, in the explicit case they will both allow `f(X2{X1{}})`. The second option simply uses the converting constructor directly, while the first option uses X2's copy or move constructor, which takes its argument from the conversion operator. The actual copy or move operation will be elided, so there is no difference in performance.